# How to execute a SQL query against a System.Data.DataTable Object?

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a `DataTable` object loaded using below code.

```
DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(dataset);
DataTable myDataTable = dataset.Tables[0];
```

I want to execute this SQL query against that `DataTable` object:

```
UPDATE myDataTable 
SET Enabled = 'YES' 
WHERE ID = '123';
```

I was able to do this using LINQ, but the requirement is to execute SQL queries against the `DataTable` object.

How can we achieve this?

Comment: Have a look at [Edit Rows in a DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tat996zc.aspx)

Comment: Thanks huMpty.. I need to dynamically create the query from string input, and there can be multiple columns to update. Any suggestions?

Comment: so... you need to dynamically generate a SQL statement which will never be seen or used by a SQL database?   "No matter how far you have gone on a wrong road, turn back."

Comment: It is not like that. An example would be, at run time, I need to change the value of the field Enabled to YES for ID 123 in the table. I am storing data in an in-memory datatable object for the time being, and hence wants to see if there is a way to execute SQL queries to update it. Only valid queries will be there.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that a DataTable isn't an implementation of SQL, although it understands very limited subset of SQL.

You can use the SELECT filter and then update the rows programmatically:

```
var myRows = myDataTable.Select("ID = '123'");
foreach (var row in myRows)
{
    row["Enabled"] = "YES";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Russ for your suggestion. The requirement is to execute update queries against the datatable at runtime. The column names are unknown at design time. So I am trying to figure out a way to perform updation at runtime. There can be multiple columns as well to update, and hence cannot use a parameterized version of your solution as well.

Comment: I would strongly suggest looking at executing directly against the database, using SqlConnection, SqlCommand and so on. If you don't know the schema at design time, then a DataTable isn't going to be the best option; Never mind that they're almost universally despised!